# Why did my most recent article fall behind an older one on my site?

Tags: loop, date

https://afrosapiophile.com/

This is is the face of my wordpress website. This article here:
https://afrosapiophile.com/2017/12/25/side-eye/

Was written on the 25th of December. This article, the newer one: 
afrosapiophile.com/2017/12/31/tariq-umar/

This one shows up BEFORE the one written on the 25th of December. Why? Can this be fixed? If this is the most recent article then it should be the first article people see. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Side Eye post is a sticky.
See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

In the Publish meta box (top right of Edit Post page), under Visibility it has "Stick this post to the front page" checked.